# How can I specify the region for every variable simultaneously in NMinimize?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I want to use `NMinimize` to find the unknown unitary matrix that solves a (possibly nonlinear) matrix equation. For example, the one that transforms the Pauli matrix $\sigma^x$ to $\sigma^y$:

$\qquad U^\dagger \sigma^x U=\sigma^y$.

Here is my code:

```
sx = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}; sy = {{0, -I}, {I, 0}};
UR = Array[ur, {2, 2}]; UI = Array[ui, {2, 2}];
U = UR + I UI; Udg = Transpose[UR - I UI];
sol = 
  NMinimize[
    Total[Total[Abs[Udg.sx.U - sy]^2 + Abs[Udg.U - IdentityMatrix[2]]^2]], 
    Flatten[{UR, UI}]];
Usol = U /. sol[[2]];
Round[ConjugateTranspose[Usol].sx.Usol] // MatrixForm
```

The output is indeed $\sigma^y$. The code is OK, but I want to improve it to run faster. Realizing that the elements of unitary matrix have absolute value smaller than 1, I can limit the $ur[i,j]$ and $ui[i,j]$ to be in the interval [-1, 1]. Is there a neat way to do this with `NMinimize`?

```
 Flatten[{UR, UI}] ∈ Interval[{-1, 1}]
```

doesn't work.

Any other improvements on my code will also be welcomed, as my research problem is much bigger; e.g., an 8$\times$8 unknown unitary matrix. I want to optimize the speed.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite confident that the minimal `U` in this case can be obtained by using [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form#Linear_algebra) as follows:

```
{λ, V} = Eigensystem[sx];
V = Normalize /@ V;
{μ, W} = Eigensystem[sy];
W = Normalize /@ W;
U = ConjugateTranspose[W].V;

ConjugateTranspose[U].sx.U == sy
```

> True

Important requirement to use this: The two matrices `sx` and `sy` have to be [normal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix), i.e., they have to satisfy the equations

```
ConjugateTranspose[sx].sx == sx.ConjugateTranspose[sx]
ConjugateTranspose[sy].sy == sy.ConjugateTranspose[sy]
```